# '\b' not working together with '\[' or '\]'

Tags: javascript, regex

I need '[se]' or 'se' followed and preceded by white or empty space in string below to be replaced with '', but [] symbols aren't matched.

`"[se] w".replace(/\b(\[?se\]?)\b/g, '') // outputs '[] w'`

Is there anything i can do to make this work as expected?

Comment: Please provide more information. Your question is a little confusing? Please provide the inputs  and required output which you want

Comment: It is clear. OP needs unambiguous word boundaries, `"[se] w".replace(/(^|\W)\[?se]?(?!\w)/g, '$1')`

Comment: try this : "[se] w".replace(/(\s*)(se|\[se\])(\s*)/g, '')